# Cómo marcar ruta entre dos puntos con api de Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

Ya tengo las coordenadas de los dos puntos, pero quisiera que en el mapa se mustre por que calles pasar para ir del punto **A** al punto **B**.
Encontré el siguiente código pero solamente marca una línea recta entre los dos puntos.

```
GoogleMap map;
 Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(puntoA, PuntoB)
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));
```

Comment: a mi me ah funcionado esto https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZIZ81fn7b4 espero que te funcione :)

Answer (score 1):

```
GoogleMap map;
 // ... get a map.
 // Add a thin red line from London to New York.
 Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));
```

Pero si quieres algo más **dinámico** que una simple línea recta, tienes que esforzarte y hacer algo así.

```
private class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String data = "";
            try {
                data = FunctionUtilities.readUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            new ParserTask().execute(result);
        }
    }

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                FunctionUtilities parser = new FunctionUtilities();
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                    points.add(position);
                }

                polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
                polyLineOptions.width(5);
                polyLineOptions.color(Color.RED);
            }

            if (polyLineOptions != null) {
                mapCU.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
            }
        }
    }
```

Y ese **AssynTask** lo mandas a llamar :

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mapCU = googleMap;
        mapUpdate(origPoint, destPoint);
    }




private void mapUpdate(LatLng originPoint, LatLng destinationPoint) {
mapCU.clear();
mapCU.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
mapCU.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + originPoint.latitude + "," + originPoint.longitude
        + "&destination=" + destinationPoint.latitude + "," + destinationPoint.longitude + "&mode=walking";

new ReadTask().execute(url);

mapCU.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(originPoint, 16));

mapCU.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(originPoint)
        .title("Origen")
        .snippet(origin)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))).showInfoWindow();

mapCU.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(destinationPoint)
        .title("Destino")
        .snippet(destination)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));


if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    return;
}
mapCU.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

Puedes guiarte de esto:

[Google Maps Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=es-419)

[Servicios Web Directions Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=es-419#Waypoints)

Answer (score 0):

Para poder obtener una linea que pase por las calles tienes que hacer una peticion a  `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/`

Yo utilizo RxJava+Retrofit para hacer la peticion de la informacion

```
public interface RutaGoogleMaps {
@GET("json")
Single<ResponseBody> obtenerRegistro(@Query("origin") String origin,
                                   @Query("destination") String destination,
                                   @Query("language") String language,
                                   @Query("units") String units,
                                   @Query("key") String key);
}
```

En este [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=es-419#RequestParameters) puedes ver los parametros que puedes enviar en tu peticion

Luego ya sea que uses retrofit o el metodo de tu preferencia para solicitar la informacion, puedes hacer uso de la libreria de `polyutils` para decodificar la respuesta y te dibuje la linea

```
//libreria a agregar a tu build.gradle
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'

JsonObject respuesta = gson.fromJson(responseBody.string(), JsonElement.class).getAsJsonObject();
String points = respuesta.get("routes").getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("overview_polyline").getAsJsonObject().get("points").getAsString();
PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions().addAll(PolyUtil.decode(points));
mGoogleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
```

Donde `responseBody` es la respuesta que recibo de retrofit, pero dependiendo de tu caso puede variar y `respuesta` es un objeto json generado a partir de lo recibido de la peticion.

En este [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=es-419#sample-response) puedes ver un ejemplo de respuesta, y el importante es `overview_polyline` que en el campo `points` que contiene una [polilinea codificada](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm?hl=es-419), y ahi es donde usas la libreria polyutils para decodificar y agregar la ruta al mapa